# Why Can't This Code Find Powers? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, math, exponentiation

App Academy's practice test says their chosen way of finding if an input is a power of 2 is to keep dividing it by 2 on a loop and check whether the end result is 1 or 0 (after having tested for the numbers 1 and 0 as inputs), which makes sense, but why won't this way work?

```
def try
  gets(num)
  counter = 0
  go = 2 ** counter

  if num % go == 0 
    return true
  else
    counter = counter + 1
  end

    return false
end
```

I can't figure out why this won't work, unless the counter isn't working.

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code.

Comment: As a note, generally `x += 1` is preferable to `x = x + 1`.

Comment: 2**0 is 1. And every number % 1 yields 0. So you will always return true.

Comment: hmm, your 'function' must have one parameter, num. add it

Comment: It looks to me like you are only evaluating whether a number is divisible by 2 (e.g. 12 is divisible by two) not if a number is a power of 2 (e.g. 12 is not a power of two)

Comment: Sorry I initially had while the if statement nested inside a counter <= num (but this didn't work either so I just put up my latest attempt today) - the while statement was after the counter = 0 so wouldn't this stop it from reseting and thus counter would keep increasing by 1 before trying if again? In other words, wouldn't this make it a loop?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.

1. First of all, there is no loop and your counter will reset to zero each time if you intend to use the method in a loop, because of `counter = 0`.
2. `counter = 0; go = 2 ** counter` basically means `go = 2 ** 0` which is `1`. Therefore `num % 1` will always be `0`
3. You actually need to divide the number and change it in the process. `12 % 4` will return `0` but you don't know by that if 12 is a power of 2.
4. [IO#gets](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-i-gets) returns a string and takes a separator as an argument, so you need to use `num = gets.to_i` to actually get a number in the variable num. You are giving `num` to `gets` as an argument, this does not do what you want.

Try:

```
# Check if num is a power of 2
#
# @param num [Integer] number to check
# @return [Boolean] true if power of 2, false otherwise
def power_of_2(num)
  while num > 1 # runs as long as num is larger than 1
    return false if (num % 2) == 1 # if number is odd it's not a power of 2
    num /= 2 # divides num by 2 on each run
  end
  true # if num reached 1 without returning false, it's a power of 2
end
```

Comment: Sorry I initially had while the if statement nested inside a counter <= num (but this didn't work either so I just put up my latest attempt today) - the while statement was after the counter = 0 so wouldn't this stop it from reseting and thus counter would keep increasing by 1 before trying if again? In other words, wouldn't this make it a loop?

Comment: This code is heavily un-idiomatic: method names are `snake_case`, not `camelCase`; the condition in a `while` loop is not enclosed in parentheses; use *either* `do` *or* a newline to separate the condition of the `while` loop from the body but not both; `(num % 2) == 1` should rather be written as `num.odd?`; the value of the last expression that is evaluated is returned implicitly, there is no need for an explicit `return`. And the invisible, non-printable soft-hyphen you have there in the method name, now that's just mean.

Comment: @JörgWMittag well i hacked that in a hurry after writing a few hundred lines of java code, so yea i mixed a lot of conventions there (like parantheses of while, return and the camelCase method names that i learned as correct java) and totaly agree with you with everything but the num.odd? method. I wanted to demonstrate how the modulo and division operator should be used. Anyway I would've been glad if you have just improved my sloppy answer istead of commenting :) and i really wonder how that hyphen got there, as it really annoyed me too when i copied the method to irb

Answer (score 0):

I add some checks for your code. Note, that `gets(num)` returns a String. Your code is fine, but not for Ruby. Ruby hates type-cross-transform like Perl does.

```
def try(num = 0)
  # here we assure that num is number
  unless (num.is_a?(Integer)) 
    puts "oh!"
    return false
  end

  counter = 0
  go = 2 ** counter

  if num % go == 0 
    return true
  else
    counter = counter + 1
  end
    return false
end
```

The general problem is "how string could use '%' operator with number?"

Try some code in the interpretator (`irb`):

```
"5" % 2
```

or

```
"5" % 0
```